# How to detect user defined encoding with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

How can I find out wether a PDF uses a user defined encoding? - preferably by PDFBox 2.0.29.

[image]

This is my current experimental approach. Any better ideas?

```
  boolean hasUserDefinedEncoding = false;
  if (document.getNumberOfPages() > 0) {
    PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
    PDResources res = page.getResources();
    for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames()) {
      PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
      String name = font.getName();
      hasUserDefinedEncoding = name == null;
      if (hasUserDefinedEncoding) break;
    }
  }
```

Edit 2023-10-25: It turns out that the document was created by TargetStream StreamEDS most likely by using the obfuscation option. Any better ideas to find out whether obufscation is used in a PDF?

I cannot share the entire document since it contains personal data. In one section it contains:

[image]

Copy/paste this section into notepad shows:

```
Gru>d%/ge der Versicheru>g si>d die A%%ge_ei>e> Versicheru>gsbedi>gu>ge> (AVB), Ausg/be 03.2017 s?wie die Bes?>dere>
Bedi>gu>ge> 0200, die Sie :us/__e> _it der !fferte/de_ A>tr/g erh/%te> ?der i_ I>ter>et ei>gesehe> h/be>
```

PDFBox result looks like this (don't know wether it belongs to the section)

```
... ]ÍËUÈ:%ÑÄÇ ...
```

Comment: If it is of type PDSimpleFont then you can call getEncoding(). Also have a look at your file in PDFDebugger.

Comment: Yes, it's of type PDSimpleFont and getEncoding() returns something valid. However, I cannot find a difference between the Encoding of a "normal" PDF and a PDF with user def encoding. E.g. Encoding.getEncodingName() == "differences" for both.
I come to this questions since my code to extract plain text from a PDF gives me hieroglyphics for a given PDF with an user def encoding. Whereas the PDFDebugger and ohter PDF viewers show readable text. 
My challenge is to find out, whether readable text can be extracted.

Comment: Considering your edit: Obfuscation is a very generic term. What kind of obfuscation are you talking about?

Comment: *"I cannot share the entire document since it contains personal data. In one section it contains:"* - Obviously we in particular need to know how it is internally built. A screenshot of what a PDF viewer shows is of lesser interest.

Comment: BTW, *"I come to this questions since my code to extract plain text from a PDF gives me hieroglyphics for a given PDF with an user def encoding."* - that does not need to be connected, fonts with custom encodings can still allow proper text extraction, and fonts with standard encodings may yet hinder text extraction.

Comment: Surely, a screenshot does not help much. I tried to give a hint to the question "what kind of obfuscating...". I do not know, what "TargetStream Technologies" use for their obfuscation. 
My approach is now to check the "creator" property. If it matches to "TargetStream..." the PDF is sent to the OCR. This will cause much more CO2 but it solves the problem.